# Multiple conditions in conditional column in PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery, m

I need help to create a custom column that will print "clear" if BOTH of two other columns have "clear" too and if both of these do not have "clear" then it prints "not clear" in the custom column.

I have the below but PowerQUery is giving me "invalid identifier" (if I click on this error it selects the first instance of "clear" in the below, suggesting that is where the issue lies):

```
if [result] = “clear” and [doc_reports.result] = “clear” then “CLEAR” else “NOT CLEAR”
```

Comment: Does using normal double quotes (`""` vs `“”`) make a difference?

Comment: Normal double quotes is the fix indeed :)

Thanks!